# total differential of $f+g$, $fg$ and $\frac fg$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be differentiable. We had in lectures that $f+g,fg,\frac fg$ are differentiable too.

As an exercise I want to prove this.

$f$ is differentiable in $x\in\mathbb R^n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ there is  a lineare function $A$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-A(h)}{\|h\|}=0$

So for $fg$ I get\begin{align*}
&\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(fg)(x+h)-(fg)(x)-A(h)}{\|h\|}\\&
=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)-A(h)}{\|h\|}
\end{align*}Now I am really stuck. How can you show with above that $fg$ is totally differentiable in $x$?

---

Solution:

\begin{align}
&\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)-(gDf+fDg)(x)h}{\|h\|}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x+h)g(x)-f(x+h)Dg(x)h}{\|h\|}\\&+\frac{f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x)-g(x)Df(x)h+f(x+h)Dg(x)h}{\|h\|}\\&-\frac{f(x)Dg(x)h}{\|h\|}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x)-Dg(x)h)}{\|h\|}+g(x)\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h}{\|h\|}+\frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))Dg(x)h}{\|h\|}
\end{align}

So the first term is $fDg$ since $f$ is continuous and differentiable. The second term is $gDf$ and the last one is 0 since $f$ is continuous and $Dg$ linear and so bounded. So the limit equals 0 and $fg$ is differentiable with derivative $gDf+fDg$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $$f(a)g(a)-f(b)g(b)=f(a)g(a)-f(a)g(b)+f(a)g(b)-f(b)g(b)$$ Does this help you at all?

Comment: so I'll get $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x+h)g(x)+f(x)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)-A(h)}{\|h\|}$$but what about $A(h)$? I have to reduce the equation to use the differentiability of $f$ and $g$ for which the corresponding limit is 0

Comment: Look at the expression you just wrote down for a minute, don't rush ahead. Can you make it any simpler?

Comment: sure, $$\dots=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x))+f(x)(g(x+h)-g(x))-A(h)}{\|h\|}$$ and as I remember the proof in $\mathbb R$ the first half will be $fDg$ and the second $gDf$. I know $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-B(h)}{\|h\|}=0$. Could I just take $A(h)/2$ and then I get the result!?

Comment: No, because you need to figure out what $A$ is in terms of the derivatives of $f,g$ and show that when you substitute this into the limit it vanishes by the definition of the derivative of $f$ you give  (and ofc $g$).

Comment: I'll guess $A=f(x)Dg(x)+g(x)Df(x)$. I'll get

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x))-(f(x)Dg(x))(h)+g(x)(f(x+h)-f(x))-(g(x)Df(x))(h)}{\|h\|}$$

If I had $f(x+h)Dg(x)$ this would work fine because I could bracket $f(x+h)$ and since $f$ is continous this would be $f$ for $h\rightarrow 0$ and the rest would be the total derivative of $g$. (analog for the rest)

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right, though the argument needs tidying up a bit. More formally, you can note $(f(x+h)-f(x))H(h)\to 0$ if the second term is bounded because the first vanishes by continuity as you say.

Comment: I think I have a solution which I added above. Would be great if you take a peek at it ;) I am just not sure about the third terme since it's '0/0'

Comment: It is almost perfect; you're right to be iffy about the last term. The thing you need to know is bounded is $H(h)=Dg (h)/\lVert h\rVert $. In the 1D case this is easy because the $h$s cancel. But still by linearity this is $Dg(\hat h)$ where that's the unit length version of $h$. This is indeed bounded. (You can figure out why.)