# Why is the total differential divided by the norm of h bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I'm trying to proof the product rule for functions $f: R^{n} \to R$. There is already a good thread on this -  [total differential of $f+g$, $fg$ and $\frac fg$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425818/total-differential-of-fg-fg-and-frac-fg).

However, I am not sure about the last step, i.e. showing that
$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))dg_{x}(h)}{\lVert h \rVert}=0$$

As the other thread mentions in the comments

\begin{align} & \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))dg_{x}(h)}{\lVert h \rVert} \\
& =\lim \limits_{h \to 0} (f(x+h)-f(x)) \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{dg_{x}(h)}{\lVert h \rVert} \\
&
\end{align}

and the first limit converges to $0$ by continuity of $f$ (since f is totally differentiable). So it remains to show that the second term is bounded.

But I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this another thought and have come up with a solution.

Since $dg_{x}(h)$ is a linear map on a finite-dimensional vector space, it is a bounded linear operator which means that $\lvert dg_{x}(h)\rvert<C \|h\|, C \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $h$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map).

Therefore, $\frac{dg_{x}(h)}{\|h\|} \leq \frac{\lvert dg_{x}(h)\rvert}{\|h\|}<C$.

Comment: NB the boundedness of the linear map $dg_x$ ( $| dg_x (h)| \le C \|h\| $ for all $h$) more directly implies that $ \left| \frac{dg_x(h)}{\|h\|}\right| \le C  $ (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator )

Comment: Indeed, as Calvin points out, with this compactness argument you are showing that there is a constant $C\ge 0$ such that $|dg_x(h)|\le C \|h\|$ for all $h\in\mathbb R^n$. It is this property the one that makes things work fine. If you skim through any treatise on differential calculus in infinite-dimensional spaces, such as the chapter "Derivatives in vector spaces" in the book "Undergraduate analysis" of Serge Lang, you will see that in that context one has to *require* that $dg_x$ is a bounded linear map.

Comment: Great, thanks to both of you. So you are saying that this argument is preferable since it is more general? Good point even though I'm only looking at $R^{n}$, it is better to use the most general agrument.

Comment: Well I guess what I'm saying is you could clean up your proof. General isn't necessarily better, especially for learning purposes. As written, I think your proof goes "$dg_x$ is a linear map on a fin. dim. vec. space, therefore bounded[!], therefore continuous, therefore bounded". I think you meant to write "$dg_x$ is linear on a f.d.v.s, therefore continuous, therefore bounded". (also note that in any normed space, a linear map is continuous iff it is bounded see e.g. http://mathonline.wikidot.com/deleted:linear-operators-are-bounded-if-and-only-if-they-re )

Comment: The way I understoof your first comment is like this. I've used the argument that a linear map is a bounded linear operator and thus continuous (as given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map). Then I've used the agrument that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. This is not necessary though since I've already shown that a linear map is bounded in the first place, but did not realize it (since I'm still quite new to vector spaces). Is that correct?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy yes, that's one way to put it- on that page, the proof that a linear map on a f.d.v.s is continuous first proves that it is bounded, then implicitly appeals to the equivalence i pointed out in most recent comment. PS to make me get a notification even when I'm not procrastinating, you should type @CalvinKhor somewhere in your comment. (I don't type `@DerivativesGuy` because I'm commenting on your answer)